# $\mathbb{Z}[i]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to the complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I am new to tensor poducts (of modules over a commutative ring with identity) and need to understand the following example to continue with the actual exercises in my material.
Namely,

> I need to know why/prove that $\mathbb{Z}[i]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}\simeq \mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, by using the universal property of the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}[i]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}$.

I have no idea how to do this, but really need to know the general procedure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: They are also isomorphic as rings.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it: you can just write down a module homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[i]\otimes \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ by $a+bi\otimes r \mapsto ra+rbi$, and show that it is an isomorphism. To see injectivity for example, you can say that if $ra + rbi = 0$ then $ra = rb = 0$ and hence $r = 0$ or $a=b=0$ in which case the tensor $a+bi\otimes r = 0$, so the map is injective. Surjectivity is similarly not too difficult.

You should also probably ensure that this is in fact a module homomorphism, and I would tend to go about doing this in a similar way as @neth, and this method does not use the universal property.

You could also show that $\mathbb{C}$ satisfies the universal property of the tensor product in this case, which would imply that $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{Z}[i]\otimes\mathbb{R}$

Comment: How would I show that $\mathbb{C}$ satisfied the universal property of the tensor product?

Comment: Given any $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ with a bilinear map $\varphi \mathbb{Z}[i] \times \mathbb{R}\to M$, show that there exists some linear map $h:\mathbb{C}\to M$ such that $\varphi = h\circ \mu$ where $\mu:(a+bi,r)\mapsto ra+rbi$. If you want me to give some hints as to how to go about this let me know...

Comment: Is this map really surjective? What is the preimage of 1 + $\pi i$ for example?

Comment: Take $\phi$ to be the map $Z[i] \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined above. Then, $\phi(1\otimes 1 + i \otimes \pi) = 1+\pi i$

Answer (score 3):

The fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{C}$ only as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules follows as $\mathbb{Z}[i]\cong\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}^{\oplus 2}\cong\mathbb{C}$.

If you need to use the universal property of tensor products somewhere, it can be used in showing that $R^{\oplus n}\otimes_R M\cong M^{\oplus n}$ for a ring $R$ and $R$-module $M$.

Comment: Could you please sketch the proof for me? As I wrote I am not yet as familiar with any of the tools this would require.

Comment: @see Sketch the proof that $R^{\oplus n}\otimes_R M \cong M^{\oplus n}$?

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with the notation $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2}$, so I'm not really sure how to prove the things you wrote in your first sentence either. We only introduced the tensor product by its universal property, and now we are supposed to somehow solve exercises in the style of the one in my opening post. I'm not sure what I have to do though.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2}$ is just notation for $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, which is just $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. I write it as $\oplus$ to emphasize that it is a direct sum of groups, as the last fact is true in the infinite case for direct sums but not direct products.

Comment: Alright thank you. Yeah if you could give me a short sketch of how to prove both $R^{\oplus n}\otimes_R M \simeq M^{\oplus n}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i]\simeq\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2}$ this would most certainly help me a lot. I have some examples similar to the above one to tackle, but I'm already stuck at this point. I tried to read some material on the tensor product and looked for examples already, but so far it wasn't of any help sadly.

Comment: Actually, at least the $\mathbb{Z}[i]\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2}$ is somewhat obvious I guess, it's just that the $\oplus$ confuses me somewhat. If it really is just the cartesian product I can do this part myself.

Comment: To give a precise sketch of $R^{\oplus n}\otimes_R M\cong M^{\oplus n}$ I would need to know what you know about the tensor product (if you define them as left adjoint to hom, the argument is short). You might be interested in the treatment of tensor product in Aluffi - Algebra Chapter 0, page 500, as it defines them in terms of their universal property with respect to bilinear maps.

Comment: No we didn't use any (real) category theory and aren't supposed to for this course. We just introduced it by the standard universal property that any bilinear map factors through the tensor product. Is this enough for you to know? Otherwise I could give you our formal definition later when I'm home. I have Aluffi's book at home as well and will read the part on tensor products later too. I'm still interested in that sketch though.

Comment: I assume the map $\oplus : R^{\oplus n}\times M\longrightarrow M^{\oplus n}, (r_1,...,r_n,m)\mapsto (r_1m,...,r_nm)$. Now given any bilinear map $R^{\oplus n}\times M\longrightarrow P$ to an $R$-module $P$ I want to show that $f$ factors through $M^{\oplus n}$. So I set $g(r_1m,...,r_nm):=f(r_1,...,r_n,m)$, which defines my $g$ on the whole of $M^{\oplus n}$. I want to show well-definedness now, but for given $(r_1m,...,r_nm)=(r'_1m,...,r'_nm)$ I fail to see why $(\prod_{i=1}^nr_i)m=(\prod_{i=1}^nr'_i)m'$, which I think I need to show. Any suggestions? And is the map $\oplus$ even correct?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea about the tensor product of $ R , Z[\sqrt{2}] $ over $Z$

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\mathbb Z[X]\otimes_\mathbb Z\mathbb R\cong \mathbb R[X]$ because both are free commutative $\mathbb R$-algebras over one element. It immediately follows that $\mathbb Z[i]\otimes_\mathbb Z\mathbb R\cong \mathbb R[i]\cong\mathbb C$

Comment: We didn't introduce algebras yet.

Comment: Algebras are modules that are rings as well. Free means that no relations hold except those required by axioms. The other answers provided down to earth explanations, so I added this one purely as something you might recognize as valuable now, or in the future, and also for future reference that is searchable at SE. If you are interested in more detailed  answer, feel free to let me know. @see